# MissingTransactionException when running NHibernate with Castle.Facilities.AutoTx

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, castle-windsor, castle-autotx

I'm trying to configure Castle Windsor with NHibernate and Castle.Facilities.AutoTx, but I keep getting problems with the `PerTransactionLifeStyleOption`. If I do

```
var sessionFactory = Container.Resolve<Func<ISession>>();
var session = sessionFactory();
```

I get the following exception (on the second line above):

```
Castle.Facilities.AutoTx.MissingTransactionException:
No transaction in context when trying to instantiate model 'NHibernate.ISession'
for resolve type 'NHibernate.ISession'. If you have verified that your call 
stack contains a method with the [Transaction] attribute, then also make sure 
that you have registered the AutoTx Facility.
    at Castle.Facilities.AutoTx.Lifestyles.PerTransactionLifestyleManagerBase.Resolve(CreationContext context) in d:\Builds\Castle.Transactions-beta\src\Castle.Facilities.AutoTx\Lifestyles\PerTransactionLifestyleManagerBase.cs:line 153
    at Castle.Facilities.AutoTx.Lifestyles.WrapperResolveLifestyleManager`1.Resolve(CreationContext context) in d:\Builds\Castle.Transactions-beta\src\Castle.Facilities.AutoTx\Lifestyles\WrapperResolveLifestyleManager.cs:line 143
    at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired)
    at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
    at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context)
    at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments)
    at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments)
    at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.TypedFactoryComponent.Resolve(IKernel kernel)
    at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Resolve.Invoke(IInvocation invocation)
    at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
    at Castle.Proxies.Func`1Proxy.Invoke()
    at IntegrationTest.NCVIB.WindsorIoC.LocalDbTest.get_Reader() in D:\Projects\NCVIB-GIT\NCVIB\src\IntegrationTest.NCVIB\WindsorIoC\LocalDbTest.cs:line 22
    at IntegrationTest.NCVIB.InspectionObjectMapTests.ReadWrite() in D:\Projects\NCVIB-GIT\NCVIB\src\IntegrationTest.NCVIB\InspectionObjectMapTests.cs:line 34
```

Here's a compilation of the setup calls I'm making (They're actually spread out across several different installers):

```
container.AddFacility<AutoTxFacility>();
container.Register(Component.For<INHibernateInstaller>().Instance(new FluentNHibernateInstaller));
container.AddFacility<NHibernateFacility>(fac => fac.Option = DefaultSessionLifeStyleOption.SessionPerTransaction);
```

The `FluentNHibernateInstaller` is shown here:

```
public class FluentNHibernateInstaller : INHibernateInstaller
{
    public FluentConfiguration BuildFluent()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
                    .DefaultSchema("dbo")
                    .ConnectionString(b => b.Is(ConnectionString ?? ConnectionStringChooser.GetConnectionString())))
            .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache().ProviderClass<SysCacheProvider>())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>().Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<EnumConvention>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(
                c => c.SetProperty(Environment.SqlExceptionConverter, typeof (MsSqlExceptionConverter).AssemblyQualifiedName))
            .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty(Environment.ShowSql, "true"));
    }

    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public void Registered(ISessionFactory factory)
    {
    }

    public bool IsDefault
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public string SessionFactoryKey
    {
        get { return "default.sf"; }
    }

    public Maybe<IInterceptor> Interceptor
    {
        get { return Maybe.None<IInterceptor>(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that that the AutoTxFacility MUST be added to the container before any any component that has a [Transaction] attribute.

I was adding the facility in one of a few IWindsorInstaller classes in which the order of installation was "random" causing the facility to be installed AFTER some of my components with transactional methods:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Install(FromAssembly.This);
```

But now I am adding the facility BEFORE installing from my installer classes:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddFacility<AutoTxFacility>();
container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
```

Here is what the usage would be like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly Func<ISession> _sessionFactory;

    public MyClass(Func<ISession> sessionFactory)
    {
       _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    [Transaction]
    public virtual void UseTheSessionForSomething()
    {
        // The transaction (and session) will be initialized
        // because of the 
        //   [Transaction] attribute
        //   AND this method is virtual
        //   AND this instance was resolved from the container
        MethodWithinTransactionScope();            
    }

    public void MethodWithinTransactionScope()
    {
       // Method just needs to be invoked in the scope of a transaction
       var session = _sessionFactory();
       session.Get<Entity>(1);
    }
}

public void Test() 
{
   var myInstance = container.Resolve<MyClass>();
   myInstanace.UseTheSessionForSomething();
}
```

Comment: The call to SessionFactory() must be made within the scope of a method that is decorated with the [Transaction] attribute.  The decorated Method must also be in an class instance that is resolved from the WindsorContainer AND the Method must be marked virtual.  I have modified my answer above with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Is the exception says; the answer is to add a transaction around the method with the line of code: `var session = sessionFactory();`

If you are getting the exception and HAVE added [Transaction] on that method, then you are not resolving the service LocalDbTest properly.

Have a look at my quick-start for a quick-start:
https://github.com/haf/Castle.Facilities.NHibernate/wiki/NHibernate-Facility---Quick-Start

---

I'm reading your code now ;), the reason that it was missing was because of this line:

https://github.com/haf/Castle.Transactions/blob/master/src/Castle.Facilities.AutoTx/AutoTxFacility.cs#L86

It's a known 'TODO' that you have to register your facility before your components, and I think this is stated in the quickstart as well.

Cheers